# Elementary OS Freya icon not showing up in BURG bootloader

Tags: release-freya

I am triple-booting with Windows 7, Linux Mint and Freya.
I installed BURG (http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-burg-boot-loader-in-ubuntu-1304-and-linuxmint/) and Super-Boot-Manager (SBM).
Everything works, but the entry for elementary OS has a question mark icon.
And none of the themes I installed with SBM do the trick about it.
How do I add an icon for Elementary?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to manually add the icon to the theme, since none of them has an elementary OS icon. I have done this before but stopped using BURG since it is no longer supported. But I remember it being pretty self-explanatory.